# .bat on WinCE not working, on windows 7 does

Tags: batch-file, windows-ce

It is tricky to figure out why executing the following code

```
SET "data_dir=Rilevamenti Prova"
SET "data_hd=Hard Disk"    
SET "data=%data_hd%\%data_dir%"

echo source path is: %data%
```

on Windows 7 I get:

source path is: Hard Disk\Rilevamenti Prova

on WinCe 4 I get:

source path is: %data%

I tried several times in several ways but no way, cannot get correctly working on WinCE. Anyone can help?

cheers
Alessandro

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is WinCE that works correctly. Command should be like `SET VarName=some value`, no quotes needed

Comment: Unfortunately no luck without quotes...I mean if I write direcly on dos prompt everything fine but executing a file .bat I get the behaviour above. On Windows 7 if I miss quotes on .bat I get malfunctioning code. Quotes are needed because of spaces inside path.

Comment: -1; quotes in set statements are never unnecessary, and help defend against pesky extra spaces being where they don't belong

Comment: @user1339161 @SomethingDark you both are wrong. `SET` doesn't require a value to be enquoted if it contains spaces. If you execute a bat file with line `set foo=bla bla & echo %foo%` you'll get `bla bla` echoed. I've tested it on Win7 right now.

Comment: @user1339161 I launched your code from the question on Win7 *without* quotes and it echoed `source path is: Hard Disk\Rilevamenti Prova`. Seek an error in your code or environment.

Comment: @Fr0st you absolutely right but the path gets problems with commands such as copy, move. I can set correctly the variable without quotes, I cannot use it properly. This is the tricky stuff.

Comment: @Fr0sT - I never said the quotes were required. Use `echo *%foo%*` instead and [you'll see why I recommended using them](http://i.imgur.com/sKscplX.png). Also, in your example you must have foo set somewhere else, because setting and echoing a variable on the same line [will not echo its updated value](http://i.imgur.com/caySsS1.png).

Comment: @user1339161 after you have set the variable you must enquote it inside commands of course. `SET Data=path with spaces {newline} copy "%Data%\srcfile" "%DestDir%"`. What's exactly the code you try and the issue you get?

Comment: @SomethingDark OK, I got your point. But this construction is a sort of `if (5 == i)` tricks. It is hardly should be used. And there's no surprise it is unsupported by WinCE's cmd. The one-liner was incorrect indeed, I tried to avoid lack of line feeds in comments by it. It worked from the prompt though. BTW you'd better advice something on the topic instead of downvoting correct answers.

Comment: @Fr0st I got the error in my code. I got not working because of I had to write the paths correctly for Hard Disk like:

\Hard Disk\filename

I was doing:

Hard Disk\filename

I didn't realize I was switching between E:\ and Hard Disk\ , with the second I had to add \ on the beginning. 

Cheers!

Comment: @Alessandro lol WinCE doesn't have named disk system indeed, is has *nix-styled one.